# Centos 8 vs Almalinux, is it okay to upgrade? A help to understand how to change OS

Tags: centos, vps

I'm stuck on whether to move my VPS with cPanel from Centos 8 to Almalinux
In several blog sites I have read that almalinux is a 1: 1 system with centos 8, so it should keep all the features without too much difficulty.

The fact is that on my VPS I have two Magento 2.3.7 sites and I have implemented the VPS with Redis and Varnish, and I wanted to add elastichsearc as well.

One of the doubts is precisely on the fact that with centos 8 I already have redis and varnish, if I had to change Centos with Almalinux, would these two extensions remain or should I reinstall them?

Another question, as I have two sites on the VPS, and both have been live for some time, what if something goes wrong?

My hosting allows me to take snapshots so somehow I could be preserved so I can go back.
But even if I have this possibility, I would need suggestions from those who are more experienced than me and if anything have already dealt with cases similar to mine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlmaLinux is 1:1 with RHEL, CentOS 8.5 is no longer supported (as from 31/12/2021) and so as time goes on differences will appear.  At the moment they are mainly bugfixes so there should be a relatively smooth transition, but the longer you leave it the worse it will become.  Your system is also increasingly vulnerable to "black hats".

[This site](https://www.tecmint.com/install-magento-on-rocky-linux-and-almalinux/) discusses installing Magneto.  I've seen cpanel support mentioned, but I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with Redis and Varnish.

[There is a forum here](https://almalinux.discourse.group/) and a [chat line here](https://chat.almalinux.org/almalinux/channels/town-square).  Official documentation is available [on the web site](https://almalinux.org/)  There is an active and knowledgeable community behind them, so I would suggest taking any worries there.

You mention snapshots, obviously before any major changes you ***must*** back up somehow.

Generally the procedure is as simple as running a script which changes the repositories from CentOS to Alma, and then reinstalls branding.  See the [instructions here](https://github.com/AlmaLinux/almalinux-deploy).  You'll also get four months of updates.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks to answare me. I follow your suggest and I opened a post on almalinux forum.